# sql update with a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Which is the correct way to do this update, is it this way :

```
UPDATE [log].codesEntered
SET    [log].codesEntered.countrycode = 
             (SELECT [user].[profile].countryCode
             FROM   [user].[profile]
                    INNER JOIN [log].codesEntered
                      ON [log].codesEntered.userid = [user].[profile].userid
             WHERE  [log].codesEntered.countryCode <> [user].[profile].countryCode
                    AND [log].codesEntered.campid = @campid
                    AND [log].codesEntered.portalid = @portalid
                    AND [user].[profile].countryCode <> ''
                    AND [user].[profile].countryCode <> '--')
```

or this way :

```
UPDATE [log].codesEntered
SET    [log].codesEntered.countrycode = [user].[profile].countryCode
FROM   [log].codesEntered
       INNER JOIN [user].[profile]
         ON [log].codesEntered.userid = [user].[profile].userid
WHERE  [log].codesEntered.countryCode <> [user].[profile].countryCode
       AND [log].codesEntered.campid = @campid
       AND [log].codesEntered.portalid = @portalid
       AND [user].[profile].countryCode <> ''
       AND [user].[profile].countryCode <> '--'
```

Comment: try visiting [this link](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-write-inner-join-in-update-query.html) for a syntax and an example too

Comment: second option looks pretty standard in terms of syntax - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server the second one is not standard SQL and can cause undeterministic results in the event that multiple joined rows can match a `codesEntered` row.

The correlated sub query version would raise an error in that event. It would also set `countrycode` to `NULL` in the event there was no match at all.

The join might be more efficient.

You could also look at `MERGE` rather than the proprietary `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax if you are on at least SQL Server 2008. This will raise an error if there is an attempt to update the same row more than once.

Comment: +1 totally agree - if the sub-query returns more than one option then it hits a problem: option 2 is standard issue ...go with that

Answer (score 0):

You can try s.t like this (my prefer way):

```
UPDATE [log].codesEntered log
SET    [log].codesEntered.countrycode =  (select countryCode from [user].[profile]   where [user].[profile].userid = log.userid)
WHERE  log.userid in 
       ( select [log].codesEntered.userid
       from [log].codesEntered join [user].[profile]
        on [log].codesEntered.userid = [user].[profile].userid
       where [log].codesEntered.countryCode <> [user].[profile].countryCode
       AND [log].codesEntered.campid = @campid
       AND [log].codesEntered.portalid = @portalid
       AND [user].[profile].countryCode <> ''
       AND [user].[profile].countryCode <> '--' )
```

This approach also works on other DMBS like oracle.

Comment: your last sentence seems to imply using `FROM` in an `UPDATE` query is wrong  - I use it a lot - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)